# Float and lambda - getting Type Error, a float is required

Tags: python, django, highcharts, lambda

I'm trying to get [Chartit](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/docs/) working with my Django project. I found that it doesn't support datetime on the x axies (it returns an error and says "is not JSON serializable".) So to fix this, I tried to work in [this hack](https://gist.github.com/rauch/3175635) which uses lambda functions. (I modified the chartit python code as specified there as well.)

This line is giving the error, "TypeError: a float is required."

```
x_sortf_mapf_mts=(None, lambda i: datetime.fromtimestamp(i).strftime("%H:%M"), False))
```

Here's the relevant part of the function:

```
cht = Chart(
            datasource = happydata,
            series_options =
            [{'options':{
            'type': 'line',
            'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
            'day': [
            'rating',]
            }}],
            chart_options =
            {'title': {
            'text': 'Ratings'},
            'xAxis': {
            'title': {
            'text': 'Time'}}}, 
        x_sortf_mapf_mts=(None, lambda i: datetime.fromtimestamp(i).strftime("%H:%M"), False))
```

I read up on lambda functions, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Any help much appreciated! Thanks.

Traceback, as requested:

```
    Traceback:
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
      111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\MYSTUFF\projects\feels2\feelsapp\views.py" in home
      82.       x_sortf_mapf_mts=(None, lambda i: datetime.fromtimestamp(i).strftime("%H:%M"), False))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\chartit\charts.py" in __init__
      25.         self.generate_plot()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\chartit\charts.py" in generate_plot
      200.                                 data = [(x_mapf(x), y) for (x, y) in data]
    File "C:\Users\MYSTUFF\projects\feels2\feelsapp\views.py" in <lambda>
      82.       x_sortf_mapf_mts=(None, lambda i: datetime.fromtimestamp(i).strftime("%H:%M"), False))

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: a float is required
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    #Create a DataPool with the data we want to retrieve.

    feels = Feel.objects.all()

    happydata = \
        DataPool(
            series=
            [{'options': {
            'source': Feel.objects.all()},
            'terms': [
            'day',
            'rating']}
        ])


    cht = Chart(
            datasource = happydata,
            series_options =
            [{'options':{
            'type': 'line',
            'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
            'day': [
            'rating',]
            }}],
            chart_options =
            {'title': {
            'text': 'Your Ratings'},
            'xAxis': {
            'title': {
            'text': 'Time'}}}, 
        x_sortf_mapf_mts=(None, lambda i: datetime.fromtimestamp(float(i)).strftime("%H:%M"), False))

    return render_to_response('happy.html',{'happychart': cht})
```

Comment: plz attach complete error stack-trace ...

Comment: Maybe ```datetime.fromtimestamp``` requires a float as the argument, what is being passed to it?

Comment: Like so? `x_sortf_mapf_mts=(None, lambda i: datetime.fromtimestamp(float(i)).strftime("%H:%M"), False))` This gives "ValueError: could not convert string to float: ".

Comment: It looks like you are passing in a non-timestamp value somewhere. Could you show us what 'happydata' is?

Comment: Thanks, Titus. Just added the relevant view.

Comment: @TitusP, aah, you were right. I checked my models and it was a CharField, rather than a DateTimeField. I changed it to DateTimeField, but now it's giving me an error of "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number." So this means i is not a string or a number? Not sure where to go from here.. thanks for the help!

Comment: Now that you are using a datetime field, you can drop the fromtimestamp. Your code should look like: lambda i: i.strftime('%H:%M')

Comment: `x_sortf_mapf_mts=(None, lambda i: i.strftime('%H:%M'), False)` ? This returns AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime' 

:S

Comment: Hmm, it thinks i is None. is your datetime field a required field? Does each entry in the DB actually have this field in it (no nulls or 0s)?

Comment: Woah, that was it! The entries in the database were CharField items, not datetime. I went and deleted them and added new items, and it seems to be working now! Thanks so much, I'd been puzzling over it for the longest time!

Comment: No prob, happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@wwii is correct, if its the lambda that is giving you the error, you are likely passing in a string. Any int or float should be able to be used, try:

```
lambda i: datetime.fromtimestamp(float(i)).strftime("%H:%M")
```

EDIT: seeing your comment to @wwii, it looks like you are probably not passing in a real number. You should try adding a print statement somewhere in your code and check the value of "i" before you create that chart.